# How show specific part of an image in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

[image: my image]

i have this picture(all of these effects are in one .png file ) i want to display for example second picture how can i use Image and ImageView in javafx to display specific part of this image ? thanks

Comment: If you used a BufferedImage, it would be really simple, but, no, JavaFX has to have its own Image class...

Comment: how can i do this with bufferedImage ?

Comment: [`BufferedImage#subImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), problem is, this isn't compatible with JavaFX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is overkill.  But with a nice set of images like you have in your question, maybe overkill is what is called for :-)

The fundamental design is the same as Uluk's, it just adjusts the Viewport of the ImageView rather than setting a clip, but the concept is the same.

*Beware => Java 8*

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

class ExploadableImageView extends ImageView {
    private final Rectangle2D[] cellClips;
    private int numCells;
    private final Duration FRAME_TIME = Duration.seconds(.5);

    public ExploadableImageView(Image explosionImage, int numCells) {
        this.numCells = numCells;

        double cellWidth  = explosionImage.getWidth() / numCells;
        double cellHeight = explosionImage.getHeight();

        cellClips = new Rectangle2D[numCells];
        for (int i = 0; i < numCells; i++) {
            cellClips[i] = new Rectangle2D(
                    i * cellWidth, 0,
                    cellWidth, cellHeight
            );
        }

        setImage(explosionImage);
        setViewport(cellClips[0]);
    }

    public void explode(EventHandler<ActionEvent> onFinished) {
        final IntegerProperty frameCounter = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        Timeline kaboom = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(FRAME_TIME, event -> {
                    frameCounter.set((frameCounter.get() + 1) % numCells);
                    setViewport(cellClips[frameCounter.get()]);
                })
        );
        kaboom.setCycleCount(numCells);
        kaboom.setOnFinished(onFinished);
        kaboom.play();
    }
}

class ExplodableItem extends StackPane {
    public ExplodableItem(Image objectImage, Image explosionImage, int numCells) {
        ImageView objectView = new ImageView(objectImage);
        ExploadableImageView explosionView = new ExploadableImageView(
                explosionImage, numCells
        );

        setMinSize(
                Math.max(
                        objectImage.getWidth(),
                        explosionView.getViewport().getWidth()
                ),
                Math.max(
                        objectImage.getHeight(),
                        explosionView.getViewport().getHeight()
                )
        );

        objectView.setPickOnBounds(false);
        objectView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            getChildren().setAll(explosionView);
            explosionView.explode(complete -> getChildren().setAll(objectView));
        });

        DropShadow drop = new DropShadow(10, Color.GOLD);
        drop.setInput(new Glow());
        objectView.setOnMouseEntered(event -> objectView.setEffect(drop));
        objectView.setOnMouseExited(event -> objectView.setEffect(null));

        getChildren().setAll(objectView);
    }
}

public class CatWhack extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static final int NUM_CELLS_PER_EXPLOSION = 6;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Image objectImage    = new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-box-icon.png");  // cat icon linkware: backlink to http://www.iconka.com required
        // looks likes imgur may have blocked direct access to following png from a Java app (somehow).
        // but you can still download the QMqbQ.png from that location 
        // and save it locally in the same directory as the CatWhack program
        // then pick it up by replacing the new Image call with:
        //    new Image(CatWhack.class.getResourceAsStream("QMqbQ.png")); 
        Image explosionImage = new Image("https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMqbQ.png");

        TilePane tiles = new TilePane();
        tiles.setPrefColumns(4);
        for (int i = 0; i <16; i++) {
            tiles.getChildren().add(
                    new ExplodableItem(objectImage, explosionImage, NUM_CELLS_PER_EXPLOSION)
            );
        }
        tiles.setMinSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        stage.setTitle("Cat Whack - Click a cat to whack it!");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(tiles));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: whack]

*Simpler example*

Here is the same concept as demonstrated in the above game, but just with a simpler system of an animated image which can be controlled via method calls rather than user mouse clicks on the image.

The animated image is similar to a [Sprite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics)).  The code below is not meant to be a production quality Sprite system (probably a true Sprite system for a game would have more functions and features), it just demonstrates very simple display of an animated image based upon a Viewport.

[image: simple image]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

class Sprite extends ImageView {
    private final Rectangle2D[] cellClips;
    private int numCells;
    private final Timeline timeline;
    private final IntegerProperty frameCounter = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    public Sprite(Image animationImage, int numCells, Duration frameTime) {
        this.numCells = numCells;

        double cellWidth  = animationImage.getWidth() / numCells;
        double cellHeight = animationImage.getHeight();

        cellClips = new Rectangle2D[numCells];
        for (int i = 0; i < numCells; i++) {
            cellClips[i] = new Rectangle2D(
                    i * cellWidth, 0,
                    cellWidth, cellHeight
            );
        }

        setImage(animationImage);
        setViewport(cellClips[0]);

        timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(frameTime, event -> {
                    frameCounter.set((frameCounter.get() + 1) % numCells);
                    setViewport(cellClips[frameCounter.get()]);
                })
        );
    }

    public void playOnce() {
        frameCounter.set(0);
        timeline.setCycleCount(numCells);
        timeline.stop();
        timeline.playFromStart();
    }

    public void playContinuously() {
        frameCounter.set(0);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.stop();
        timeline.playFromStart();
    }

    public void stop() {
        frameCounter.set(0);
        setViewport(cellClips[frameCounter.get()]);
        timeline.stop();
    }
}

public class SpriteSample extends Application {
    private static final int NUM_CELLS_PER_ANIMATION = 6;
    private static final Duration FRAME_TIME = Duration.seconds(.5);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // looks likes imgur may have blocked direct access to following png from a Java app (somehow).
        // but you can still download the QMqbQ.png from that location 
        // and save it locally in the same directory as the CatWhack program
        // then pick it up by replacing the new Image call with:
        //    new Image(Sprite.class.getResourceAsStream("QMqbQ.png")); 
        Image tilesheetImage = new Image(SpriteSample.class.getResourceAsStream("QMqbQ.png"));
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(tilesheetImage, NUM_CELLS_PER_ANIMATION, FRAME_TIME);

        ToggleButton animationControl = new ToggleButton("Animate");
        animationControl.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (animationControl.isSelected()) {
                animationControl.setText("Stop");
                sprite.playContinuously();
            } else {
                animationControl.setText("Animate");
                sprite.stop();
            }
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, sprite, animationControl);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just beware, not every one will be using Java 8 ;)

Comment: After some experiments I found out that using separate Images (setImage()) has a much better performance >100% compared to the setViewport, it has also a better GC performance. I agree that the setViewport() method is cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

You can utilize the clip property of the `Node`, along with x property of the `ImageView`. Below is a demo showing the part of image in timeline, like a gif animated picture:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    Group root = new Group();
    Image image = new Image(this.getClass().getResource("your.png").toExternalForm());

    final int numberOfFrames = 6; // in image
    double frameWidth = image.getWidth() / numberOfFrames;
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, frameWidth, image.getHeight());
    final ImageView view = new ImageView(image);

    Rectangle mask = new Rectangle(frameWidth, image.getHeight());
    view.setClip(mask);

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfFrames; i++) {
        KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(i), new KeyValue(view.xProperty(), -frameWidth * i, Interpolator.DISCRETE));
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
    }
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    root.getChildren().add(view);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

Comment: thanks , but how can i show each image in first frame (i mean if i have 6 part of image like my image in the top i show all images in the first image )

Comment: What would be the method to call for manually shifting the mask on the Image? (without using the KeyFrame to repeatedly do it)

Answer (score 3):

As someone who is new to JavaFX, I had the same question.  The question asks for much less than the above answers provide. We just want to manually select and display a portion of the image in an ImageView without animation.  Here is the simplest solution wherein the user enters the image number and presses a button to display the desired image part.

```
package com.pakzaban;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextField numberField;
    private final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 50;
    private final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 80;
    private int imageNumber = 1;

    public void onSetImagePressed(){
        try {
            imageNumber = Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText());

            //SET THE WHOLE IMAGE INTO IMAGEVIEW
            Image wholeImage = new Image("com/pakzaban/wholePicture.png");
            imageView.setImage(wholeImage);

            //SET THE VIEWPORT TO DESIRED PART OF THE IMAGE
            Rectangle2D imagePart = new Rectangle2D((imageNumber - 1) * IMAGE_WIDTH, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
            imageView.setViewport(imagePart);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image 4 selected]

Comment: The alternative (more resource-intensive) strategy would be to create a new cropped image using PixelReader as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802374/effective-image-cropping-in-javafx