# JavaFx - Creating animation from Image array

Tags: image, animation, image-processing, video, javafx

I have array of Image in JavaFx. I want create a clip video (animation) from those images, including sound file.
How Can I achieve this?

**NOTE:** I want to get a video file at the end of the process (avi, mp4 ...).

This is my array:

```
Image[] frames
```

I tried use "keyFrame" class... but without success:

```
        ImageView destImageView = new ImageView();
        Group group;
        group = new Group();
        group.setTranslateX(300);
        group.setTranslateY(450);

        Image[] frames = m.getFrames();
        KeyFrame[] kf = new KeyFrame[frames.length];
        for(int i=0;i<frames.length;i++){
            kf[0] =new KeyFrame(new Duration(0), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
//                  destImageView.setImage();
//                  group.getChildren().setAll(destImageView);

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: This question is `too broad` and unless asked with specific scenario's and supplied with tried code, is most likely to get closed.

Comment: You can create a [sprite animation](http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-sprite-animation-with-javafx/) or a [cat whack animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440980/how-show-specific-part-of-an-image-in-javafx), but really that is nothing like producing an avi or mp4, so I doubt that doing so will not help you achieve your end goal - there is no in-built avi/mp4 export function in the JavaFX core libraries.

Comment: What about the sound Ramz?  (I'm asking you) What is your question?

Comment: @jewelsea  I want add a sound to the animation.

Comment: You can use a [MediaPlayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) or an [AudioClip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) to playback audio using JavaFX.  Read the [JavaFX media documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(frame, null), "png", new File(directory, fileName));
```

to save each image as a png file.

Make sure to give the frames sequentially numbered filenames, e.g. img0000.png, img0001.png etc..

Then use ImageJ/Fiji (https://imagej.net/Fiji/Downloads)
to import the image sequence and save as an avi file.   Alternatively, as ImageJ is open-source and written in Java you could import and use directly the ImageJ class

> `ij.plugin.filter.AVI_Writer`

You could then convert it to an mp4 or other format using VLC Player, for example.