# how to decrease amount of new objects

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making something like minecraft copy but in 2D. I use javafx and this is my code:

```
package com.ppl.pixelplandia;

import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Generation {
    private final int BLOCK_SIZE = 64;
    private float cam_x = 0.0f;
    private float cam_y = 63.0f;
    private final String grass_path = "grass.png";
    private final String cobblestone_path = "cobblestone.png";



    public GridPane move(float nx, float ny, int wx, int wy) throws URISyntaxException {
        System.out.println("use");
        int[] d = {0, 0};
        GridPane returnst = new GridPane();
        returnst.getChildren().clear();
        for (float x = ((float) wx / 2 / BLOCK_SIZE); d[0] < Math.ceil((double) wx / BLOCK_SIZE); x++) {
            d[0]++;
            d[1] = 0;
            for (float y = ((float) wy / 2 / BLOCK_SIZE); d[1] < Math.ceil((double) wy / BLOCK_SIZE); y--) {
                d[1]++;
                if ((int)(y + cam_y + ny) > 63 || (int) (y + cam_y + ny) < 0) {
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(y + cam_y + ny) + " ' " + d[1]);
                    if (d[1] == 1) {
                        int r = (int) (ny % BLOCK_SIZE);
                        Rectangle re = new Rectangle(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE - r, Color.BLACK);
                        returnst.add(re, d[0], d[1]);
                    }
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, Color.BLUE);
                    returnst.add(r, d[0], d[1]);
                    continue;
                }
                if ((int) (y + cam_y + ny) == 63) {
                    if (d[1] == 1) {
                        int r = wy % BLOCK_SIZE;
                        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource(grass_path).toURI().toString());
                        WritableImage croppedImage = new WritableImage(
                                image.getPixelReader(),
                                0, r,
                                (int) image.getWidth(), (int) (image.getHeight() - r)
                        );

                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(croppedImage);
                        returnst.add(imageView, d[0], d[1]);
                    }
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(y + cam_y + ny) + " : " +d[1]);
                    returnst.add(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource(grass_path).toURI().toString())), d[0], d[1]);
                }
                else if ((int) (y + cam_y + ny) > 0 && (int) (y + cam_y + ny) < 63) {
                    if (d[1] == 1) {
                        int r = wy % BLOCK_SIZE;
                        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource(cobblestone_path).toURI().toString());
                        WritableImage croppedImage = new WritableImage(
                                image.getPixelReader(),
                                0, r,
                                (int) image.getWidth(), (int) (image.getHeight() - r)
                        );

                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(croppedImage);
                        returnst.add(imageView, d[0], d[1]);
                    }
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(y + cam_y + ny) + " . " + d[1]);
                    returnst.add(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource(cobblestone_path).toURI().toString())), d[0], d[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        cam_y += ny;
        cam_x += nx;
        return returnst;
    }
}
```

And everything is ok, but when i make this function too many times, memory usage go to 1GB.

I tried to create one ImageView for grass, second for cobblestone, but then it was duplicate. I have no idea what mistake I'm making.

Comment: Instead of making multiple images, use a single image for multiple image views. If you need to display only a portion of it, you can set the image view's viewport.

Comment: Perhaps consider a [tile engine](https://www.mapeditor.org/).  [FXGL](https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL/wiki/Building-Levels-Using-Tiled-Map-Editor-(FXGL-11)) supports that.  I don't know if that would be useful to you or not, but seems a bit similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can also consider a [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).  That is kind of how virtualized controls like ListView work in JavaFX (there are just a few nodes whose contents get updated).  Explaining how to accomplish that in the context of your example is beyond what I would answer here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like, in particular, you're looking at generating an image every time you iterate through your loop, which is very expensive. The block of code below has the "new" key word. This means that this is a completely new object, and because of that, it's adding memory every time it's called.

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource(grass_path).toURI().toString());
```

Given that, tracing through the snippet below, there are two instances of an image being created. The first is when you're declaring the variable image. The second time occurs the when you do returnst.add(). In the case of d[1] == 1, you're adding it twice, which is likely causing the duplication.

```
if ((int) (y + cam_y + ny) == 63) {
    if (d[1] == 1) {
        int r = wy % BLOCK_SIZE;
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource(grass_path).toURI().toString());
        WritableImage croppedImage = new WritableImage(
            image.getPixelReader(),
            0, r,
            (int) image.getWidth(), (int) (image.getHeight() - r)
        );

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(croppedImage);
        returnst.add(imageView, d[0], d[1]);
    }
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(y + cam_y + ny) + " : " +d[1]);
    returnst.add(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource(grass_path).toURI().toString())), d[0], d[1]);
}
```

Instead, preloading images and pointing to said image instead of creating a new one will be more memory efficient. There are several ways of doing this. Using a map to store all the textures if there a lot of them is one option, but it seems you only have 2 at this moment, so you may be able to just declare an image instance per separate image at the top of your code as a constant in your Generation class and reuse them instead of making a new one every time.

Comment: Even removing the duplicate image creation would still leave very inefficient code, though. There is no need to create a new image just to have a cropped view of it. The OP doesn’t provide a mre here, but it looks just just one image instance would suffice for the entire code posted.

Comment: I'm aware there is pretty inefficient code here, but I scoped the issue to memory since the title of the post is asking about "new objects". The duplication was specifically brought up in the original post, so I highlighted that. That said, rereading my last paragraph was a bit ambiguous, so I clarified it a little more.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating `ImageView`s in a `for { ... }` loop, and displaying them. Each time you create an `ImageView` you do so from a new `Image` instance.

There is no need to do this: multiple `ImageView`s can share the same image instances. Note that `Image` objects contain the image data, which can potentially be quite a large amount of data. The `ImageView` objects just describe how to display the images (which portion, should it be zoomed or shrunk, etc.). As the [`ImageView` documentation says](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html):

> This class allows ... specifying a viewport into the source image for restricting the pixels displayed by this ImageView.

So even if you need to crop the image for some of the views, there is no need to create a new copy of the `Image` each time. Simply specify the viewport for the image view.

From the code you posted, you only load images from two different resources. This means you should have only two `Image` instances. You can do the following in your `Generation` class:

```
public class Generation {

    private static final Image grassImage = new Image(Generation.class.getResource(grassPath).toExternalForm());
    private static final Image cobblestoneImage = new Image(Generation.class.getResource(cobblestonePath).toExternalForm());

    // ...
}
```

And then to create the image views:

```
                if ((int) (y + cam_y + ny) == 63) {
                    if (d[1] == 1) {
                        int r = wy % BLOCK_SIZE;
                        Rectangle2D viewport = new Rectangle2D(0, r, grassImage.getWidth(), grassImage.getHeight() - r);

                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(grassImage);
                        imageView.setViewport(viewport);
                        returnst.add(imageView, d[0], d[1]);
                    }
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(y + cam_y + ny) + " : " +d[1]);
                    returnst.add(new ImageView(grassImage), d[0], d[1]);
                }
                else if ((int) (y + cam_y + ny) > 0 && (int) (y + cam_y + ny) < 63) {
                    if (d[1] == 1) {
                        int r = wy % BLOCK_SIZE;
                        Rectangle2D viewport = new Rectangle2D(0, r, cobblestoneImage.getWidth(), cobblestoneImage.getHeight() - r);
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(cobblestoneImage);
                        imageView.setViewport(viewport);
                        returnst.add(imageView, d[0], d[1]);
                    }
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(y + cam_y + ny) + " . " + d[1]);
                    returnst.add(new ImageView(cobblestoneImage), d[0], d[1]);
                }
```

Note there is no code to create and `Image` instances (including `WritableImage`s) in the latter code block.

Comment: okay, and what should i do with rectangle objects? (it's generating when y > 63 or y < 0)

Comment: @Lamowy `Rectangle`s are node subclasses; they are directly added to the scene graph. No object can appear more than once in the scene graph so you can't reuse them. But a `Rectangle` will consume far less memory than an `Image`.

Comment: Quoting a comment by user Waverick from a [related question: How show specific part of an image in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440980/how-show-specific-part-of-an-image-in-javafx/23442447#comment43943645_23442447) -> "After some experiments I found out that using separate Images (setImage()) has a much better performance >100% compared to the setViewport, it has also a better GC performance. I agree that the setViewport() method is cleaner."

Answer (score -1):

i solved the problem by adding two arraylists. First for imageviews and second for rectangles.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).