# Center crop image JavaFX

Tags: java, image, javafx, scaletype

How can I accomplish Android `scaleType="centerCrop"` using JavaFX?

I have my image view:

```
ImageView myImage = new ImageView("https://example.com/image/my_image.png");

//maybe
//myImage.scaleType = "centerCrop";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to crop and resize JavaFX Image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398888/how-to-crop-and-resize-javafx-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @TravisF for the post, I've implemented the last solution to make the image always has the same height, widht and position (center).

```
double newMeasure = (userImage.getImage().getWidth() < userImage.getImage().getHeight()) ? userImage.getImage().getWidth() : userImage.getImage().getHeight();
double x = (userImage.getImage().getWidth() - newMeasure) / 2;
double y = (userImage.getImage().getHeight() - newMeasure) / 2;

Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D(x, y, newMeasure, newMeasure);
userImage.setViewport(rect);
userImage.setFitWidth(150);
userImage.setFitHeight(150);
userImage.setSmooth(true);
```