# Center crop image in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, image, javafx

I am familiarizing myself with Javafx and straight from the box I have noticed it lacks scaletypes, in Android we have what we call `CenterCrop`, when an image is smaller or larger or has dimension ratio not equating to your imageview it zooms the image and crops it according to imageview dimensions, in Javafx I cannot do that, does anyone know a way of accomplishing that?

Comment: The [documentation for `ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) has examples of zooming into part of an image. Did you try that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a clipping mask to achieve the cropping part. 
Every [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setClip-javafx.scene.Node-) has the method `public final void setClip(Node value)` which allows you to use another node as a mask.

By using setClip with an ImageView and combinign with some Bindings to the width and height, you should be able to implement your own class, that behaves according to what you describe.

Update:
Ok, after checking again, it looks like the question was already asked:   [Center crop image JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668528/center-crop-image-javafx)

The code presented there should solve your problem. I copied it here for easier reference.

```
double newMeasure = (userImage.getImage().getWidth() < userImage.getImage().getHeight()) ? userImage.getImage().getWidth() : userImage.getImage().getHeight();
double x = (userImage.getImage().getWidth() - newMeasure) / 2;
double y = (userImage.getImage().getHeight() - newMeasure) / 2;  

Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D(x, y, newMeasure, newMeasure);
userImage.setViewport(rect);
userImage.setFitWidth(150);
userImage.setFitHeight(150);
userImage.setSmooth(true);
```

Comment: to be honest I was kind of looking for a code representation of the answer, I know I have to use the node but what am lacking is implementation.

Comment: this method only crops the image and stretches it until it fits the parent, instead, center crop zooms into the image and crops it to match the parent