# How to select particular region of image by mouse event in webview and crop by key event by using space?

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, keyevent

I have tried this for my selection and its running properly but my requirement is only for one box and its selecting complete scene.

```
   package verticalseperator;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author biznis
 */
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author biznis
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.effect.Light.Point;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;


/**
 *
 * Created on: 20.03.2012
 *
 * @author Sebastian Damm
 */
public class HV extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

          StackPane root = new StackPane();

        HBox hbox = new HBox(30); // create a HBox to hold 2 vboxes        

        // create a vbox with a textarea that grows vertically
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        //Label label1 = new Label("");

        final WebView img = new WebView();
        final WebEngine Img = img.getEngine();


         final Rectangle selection = new Rectangle();
       final Point anchor = new Point();

      img. setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) ->{
     anchor.setX(event.getX());
            anchor.setY(event.getY());
            selection.setX(event.getX());
            selection.setY(event.getY());
            selection.setFill(null); // transparent 
            selection.setStroke(Color.BLACK); // border
         root.getChildren().add(selection);
                  });
       img. setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) ->
            { 
          selection.setWidth(Math.abs(event.getX() - anchor.getX()));
            selection.setHeight(Math.abs(event.getY() - anchor.getY()));
            selection.setX(Math.min(anchor.getX(), event.getX()));
            selection.setY(Math.min(anchor.getY(), event.getY()));
            }); 
        img. setOnMouseReleased((MouseEvent event) ->{

              System.out.printf("X: %.2f, Y: %.2f, Width: %.2f, Height: %.2f%n", 
                    selection.getX(), selection.getY(), selection.getWidth(), selection.getHeight());
            root.getChildren().remove(selection);
            selection.setWidth(0);
            selection.setHeight(0);
        });

        img.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (KeyEvent e) -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE ) {
            PixelReader reader = img.getPixelReader();
    WritableImage newImage = new WritableImage(reader, X, Y, Width,Height);
            }
            });
        img.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (KeyEvent e) -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ADD || e.getCode() == KeyCode.EQUALS || e.getCode() == KeyCode.PLUS) {
                System.out.println("YES");
                img.setZoom(img.getZoom() * 1.1);
            } else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.SUBTRACT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.MINUS) {
                System.out.println("YES");
                img.setZoom(img.getZoom() / 1.1);
            }
        });
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(img);
        // create a vbox that grows horizontally inside the hbox
        VBox vbox2 = new VBox();
        final WebView browser = new WebView();
        final WebEngine wb2 = browser.getEngine();
        final WebView browser1 = new WebView();
        final WebEngine wb1 = browser1.getEngine();
        wb1.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
                .addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                        if (newState == Worker.State.SCHEDULED) {
                            primaryStage.setTitle(wb1.getLocation());
                            String trgurl = wb1.getLocation();
                            System.out.println(trgurl);
                            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                final WebEngine wb1 = browser1.getEngine();
                                if (wb1.getLocation().contains("img")) {
                                    System.out.println("BrowserPane.ChangeListener cancelling " + wb1.getLocation());
                                    wb1.getLoadWorker().cancel();
                                    if (trgurl.matches("(.*)img=(.*)")) {
                                        int n = trgurl.indexOf("img=");
                                        //String str1 = Integer.toString(n);
                                        System.out.println(n + 4);
                                        int len = trgurl.length();
                                        System.out.println("string length is: " + trgurl.length());
                                        System.out.println(trgurl.substring(n + 4, len));
                                        String find = "file:" + trgurl.substring(n + 4, len);
                                        System.out.println(find);
                                        Img.load(find);


                                        if (trgurl.matches("(.*)target=wb2(.*)")) {
                                            int n1 = trgurl.indexOf("target=wb2");
                                            String str1 = Integer.toString(n1 + 10);
                                            System.out.println(n1 + 10);
                                            System.out.println(trgurl.substring(0, n1 + 10));
                                            String find1 = "" + trgurl.substring(0, n1 + 10);
                                            System.out.println(find1);
                                            // boolean cancel();
                                            wb2.load(find1);

                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                        }

                        if (browser1.getEngine().getLoadWorker().getState() == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            if (wb1.getLocation().contains("noob=1&noshell=1&ini=")) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "got " + wb1.getLocation());
                                int n4 = wb1.getLocation().indexOf("ini=");
                                String str4 = Integer.toString(n4 + 4);
                                System.out.println(n4 + 4);
                                int n5 = wb1.getLocation().indexOf("&output_format=html");
                                String str5 = Integer.toString(n5 + 19);
                                System.out.println(n5 + 19);
                                String find4 = wb1.getLocation().substring(n4 + 4, n5);
                                System.out.println(find4);
                                String html = (String) wb1.executeScript("document.documentElement.innerText");
                                try {
                                    System.out.write(html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(HV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                                String html1 = html.replace('|', '\n');
                                System.out.println(html1);
                                String h1 = html1.replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");
                                // System.out.println(html1);
                                String Path = "C:/temp";
                                Path = Path + "/";
                                File newFile = new File(Path + find4 + ".ini");

                                try {
                                    newFile.createNewFile();
                                    if (newFile.exists()) {
                                        newFile.delete();

                                    }
                                    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newFile, true)) {
                                        writer.write(h1);
                                        writer.flush();
                                        writer.close();
                                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(HV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(HV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }

                                if (html.contains("date_data_path=")) {
                                    int n6 = html.indexOf("date_data_path=");
                                    String str6 = Integer.toString(n6 + 15);
                                    System.out.println(n6 + 15);
                                    int len1 = html.length();
                                    System.out.println("string length is: " + html.length());
                                    String find2 = html.substring(n6 + 15, len1 - 1);
                                    System.out.println(find2);
                                    String pathname = "C:";
                                    String cuts = "cuts";
                                    pathname += find2 + "/" + cuts;
                                    System.out.println(pathname);
                                    File directory = new File(pathname);
                                    if (!directory.exists()) {
                                        directory.mkdirs();
                                    }
                                    String pathname1 = "C:";
                                    String db = "db";
                                    pathname1 += find2 + "/" + db;
                                    System.out.println(pathname1);
                                    File directory1 = new File(pathname1);
                                    if (!directory1.exists()) {
                                        directory1.mkdirs();
                                    }
                                    String pathname2 = "C:";
                                    String ocr = "ocr";
                                    pathname2 += find2 + "/" + ocr;
                                    System.out.println(pathname2);
                                    File directory2 = new File(pathname2);
                                    if (!directory2.exists()) {
                                        directory2.mkdirs();
                                    }
                                    String pathname3 = "C:";
                                    String output = "output";
                                    pathname3 += find2 + "/" + output;
                                    System.out.println(pathname3);
                                    File directory3 = new File(pathname3);
                                    if (!directory3.exists()) {
                                        directory3.mkdirs();
                                    }
                                    String pathname4 = "C:";
                                    String scans = "scans";
                                    pathname4 += find2 + "/" + scans;
                                    System.out.println(pathname4);
                                    File directory4 = new File(pathname4);
                                    if (!directory4.exists()) {
                                        directory4.mkdirs();
                                    }
                                    /*  img.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
             if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.F5) {
                 System.out.println("F5 PRESSED");
             File f = new File("pathname:\\Output.jpg");
                // RenderedImage image = null;
                 try {
                     ImageIO.write(f);
                 } catch (IOException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(HV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }
             }
        });*/
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

                });

        wb1.load("http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/");
        // String url = "https://eclipse.org";
        // Load a page from remote url.
        //  webEngine.load(url);

        vbox2.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        vbox2.setSpacing(3);
        vbox2.getChildren().addAll(browser1, browser);

        HBox.setHgrow(vbox2, Priority.ALWAYS);

        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
//        StackPane.setMargin(hbox, new Insets(20));

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox, vbox2);
        root.getChildren().add(hbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200); // the stack pane is the root node
        //scene.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);

    }
}
```

and its running properly but the problem is is selecting the complete scene i want only on one box vbox how can i do it error log

```
 run:
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=login&do=login
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=mm-pm-workdate
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=mm-pm-workdate
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=mm-pm-ini&noob=1&noshell=1&ini=rajveersingh&output_format=html
    83
    114
    rajveersingh
    |[server]||[app]|host_name=pmms.ankiti.com|ns=|session_name=pmms_ankiti_com|lang=en||[portal]|host_name=mms.ankiti.com|ns=|locale=en|domain=pmms.ankiti.com|ent_id=|app=mm-pmms|sec_ns=ankiti|sec_conf=sec-staff-lgc|sec_permissions=mms.ankiti.com|locales=mmstech|email=service@pressmonitor.com|email_name=Press Monitor|email_cc=news@ankiti.com||[shell]|id=wssoj75f2|host_name=pmms.ankiti.com|domain=ankiti.com|ent_id=|locale=|head= |header_bar=

    MMS Print

    |header_brand=|header_menu=|footer_bar=|footer_brand=|footer_menu=|change_at=2017-07-04 03:38:25||[user]|id=7f701032821e1e4d69cfcf7ee|ns=ankiti|ent_id=ank-1|code=mm-dc-rajveer|name=Rajveer verma|user_id=rajveersingh.kumar5@gmail.com|password=$2y$10$b8SLaZYPW/XAZWHWgaVg0.aL4L6sxgmpEnZrOLsGiC3hQu/22xR/m|password_old=*AAD9BAB0626ADA4743CC7582CC20E992C509D43|phone=9990367022|status=|status_remark=|permissions=mms.ankiti.com|created_at=2016-08-14 04:47:47|login_at=2017-10-25 11:00:02|change_at=2017-06-07 14:23:13|logout=`sec_loggedinas Rajveer verma `sec_logout||[pm]|work_date=2017-10-25|work_till=2017-10-25 23:59:59|work_from=2017-10-25 00:00:00|ns=pmin|centre=delhi|ymd=20171025|bar=PM Workdate: 2017-10-25 NS: pmin From: 2017-10-25 00:00:00 Till: 2017-10-25 23:59:59||[pml]|work_date_long=Wednesday, 25th October 2017|work_date=2017-10-25|year_data_dir=//192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017|month_data_dir=//192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710|date_data_dir=//192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025|date_data_path=/sata1/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025|
    [server]

    [app]
    host_name=pmms.ankiti.com
    ns=
    session_name=pmms_ankiti_com
    lang=en

    [portal]
    host_name=mms.ankiti.com
    ns=
    locale=en
    domain=pmms.ankiti.com
    ent_id=
    app=mm-pmms
    sec_ns=ankiti
    sec_conf=sec-staff-lgc
    sec_permissions=mms.ankiti.com
    locales=mmstech
    email=service@pressmonitor.com
    email_name=Press Monitor
    email_cc=news@ankiti.com

    [shell]
    id=wssoj75f2
    host_name=pmms.ankiti.com
    domain=ankiti.com
    ent_id=
    locale=
    head= 
    header_bar=

    MMS Print


    header_brand=
    header_menu=
    footer_bar=
    footer_brand=
    footer_menu=
    change_at=2017-07-04 03:38:25

    [user]
    id=7f701032821e1e4d69cfcf7ee
    ns=ankiti
    ent_id=ank-1
    code=mm-dc-rajveer
    name=Rajveer verma
    user_id=rajveersingh.kumar5@gmail.com
    password=$2y$10$b8SLaZYPW/XAZWHWgaVg0.aL4L6sxgmpEnZrOLsGiC3hQu/22xR/m
    password_old=*AAD9BAB0626ADA4743CC7582CC20E992C509D43
    phone=9990367022
    status=
    status_remark=
    permissions=mms.ankiti.com
    created_at=2016-08-14 04:47:47
    login_at=2017-10-25 11:00:02
    change_at=2017-06-07 14:23:13
    logout=`sec_loggedinas Rajveer verma `sec_logout

    [pm]
    work_date=2017-10-25
    work_till=2017-10-25 23:59:59
    work_from=2017-10-25 00:00:00
    ns=pmin
    centre=delhi
    ymd=20171025
    bar=PM Workdate: 2017-10-25 NS: pmin From: 2017-10-25 00:00:00 Till: 2017-10-25 23:59:59

    [pml]
    work_date_long=Wednesday, 25th October 2017
    work_date=2017-10-25
    year_data_dir=//192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017
    month_data_dir=//192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710
    date_data_dir=//192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025
    date_data_path=/sata1/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025

    1482
    string length is: 1524
    /sata1/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025
    C:/sata1/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025/cuts
    C:/sata1/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025/db
    C:/sata1/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025/ocr
    C:/sata1/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025/output
    C:/sata1/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025/scans
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=home&ini=rajveersingh
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?win=IBB&module=mm-pm-headlines
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=mm-pm-headlines&do=subject&subject_uid=Z10
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=mm-pm-edit&clip_id=11.2017-10-25.122&target=wb2&notb=1&img=//192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025/cuts/1318.jpg
    BrowserPane.ChangeListener cancelling http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=mm-pm-edit&clip_id=11.2017-10-25.122&target=wb2&notb=1&img=//192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025/cuts/1318.jpg
    111
    string length is: 174
    //192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025/cuts/1318.jpg
    file://192.168.2.18/pm8/data/pmin/2017/201710/20171025/cuts/1318.jpg
    99
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=mm-pm-edit&clip_id=11.2017-10-25.122&target=wb2
    http://192.168.2.18/a3/host/pmms.ankiti.com/?module=mm-pm-edit&clip_id=11.2017-10-25.122&target=wb2
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = StackPane@3e238241[styleClass=root]
    X: 171.00, Y: 125.00, Width: 242.00, Height: 134.00
    X: 409.00, Y: 259.00, Width: 0.00, Height: 0.00
 at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
at verticalseperator.HV.lambda$start$0(HV.java:94)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

this is the error i'm  getting while selection.

Comment: Please post your complete error

Comment: i had updated my error log its quite big.

Comment: Your question and and code doesn't seem related. You asked for a region selection in image by mouse event and crop that by key event but in your code you are just listening for a mouse event and printing the current coordinate values. And for listening mouse events you must create a handler with parameter 'MouseEvent'. And why you are using two handle methods?? Just use the overridden one.

Comment: so how to do selection as im trying by listening to mouse and then print coordinates i dont know im wrong or right so plz help me with example please

Comment: You can get the starting coordinate by 'setOnMousePressed' and the end coordinate by 'setOnMouseReleased'. And by the starting and end coordinates you can get the selected region then for cropping go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802374/effective-image-cropping-in-javafx

Comment: thnks let me try then will tell

Comment: `img.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() 
{
            Point start = new Point();

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
                start = me.getPoint();
               
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                Point end = me.getPoint();
                }});`                                                                                          but im getting error in mousemotion listener line cannot find symbol

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're setting the event handler correctly? If you take a look at the method signature of `setOnMousePressed`([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnMousePressed-javafx.event.EventHandler-)), you will see that you're not specifying the input event type.

Typically the event handler should be added like this:

```
img.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("X: " + event.getX() + " Y: " + event.getY());
    }
});
```

Comment: as by setting the event handler like this im getting compile time error type argument mouse event is not within  bounds of type variable t.

Comment: and but by only adding mouse pressed event i dont think its possible to select a area in image mousedragged and mouse relaese should be use can u help me how to this

Comment: There should be no compiler errors. Please update your question with a more complete example that contains all imports

Comment: thats k but i dont thing that only by this i can select a region

Comment: First, you asked about the exception. Second, your code is not working and should be fixed first in order to solve the selection problem

Comment: It seems that you're using the wrong imports.  `java.awt.MouseEvent` and  `java.awt.MouseMotionAdapter` are not part of javafx

Comment: import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent; im using this also but nothing happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156345/discussion-between-narendra-kr-and-shaka-b).

Comment: Post a more complete example with the main or JavaFX's Application class and all imports

Comment: k im updating in question

Comment: as i had debug mouse pressed is working but how to do selection by dragging .

Answer (score 0):

get the coordinates by this

```
    private int x,y,w,h;

    public void getCordinates() {
        img.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int) event.getY();
            }
        });

        img.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                w = (int) (event.getX() - x);
                h = (int) (event.getY() - y);
            }
        });
    }
```

And then get the cropped image by adding this line to you space key action listener

```
    PixelReader reader = srcImage.getPixelReader();
    WritableImage newImage = new WritableImage(reader, x, y, w, h);
```

Here `srcImage` is the image from which you want to select region, so replace it by the image you loaded in your code. And newImage is the cropped image

Comment: thnks @IR but by adding this my key listener also stop working.please tell me the problem. this is a exception Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at verticalseperator.HV.lambda$start$0(HV.java:83)

Comment: This seems like some initialization exception which is in line number 83 of HV.java. And i have no idea what you have written in that line. Don't know how to help you out @Narendra.kr .

Comment: img.setOnMousePressed(  (MouseEvent event) -> {
     int  x = (int) event.getX();
     int  y = (int) event.getY();
          }); this is on 81 ,82,83 line

Comment: either u can help me over chat as i can see u had hide your chat section.

Comment: Don't it will work or not but try intializing x and y globally

Comment: im getting compile time error globally thats why i had use like this

Comment: I think the problem is with the 'img'. Try sorting out that if you have initialized and set correctly. Because i just tried with a imageView and it worked perfectly for me. You are using webView and may be you haven't used that correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156348/discussion-between-ir-emon-and-narendra-kr).